# In RouteConfig, how can I IgnoreRoute for this "Rejected-By-UrlScan" path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to apply an IgnoreRoute to a path that contains "Rejected-By-UrlScan", and don't understand the syntax. The MSDN documentation here provides no examples.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.ignoreroute(v=vs.118).aspx

Here is an example path that I'm dealing with:

```
http://example.com/Rejected-By-UrlScan?~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

These are some IgnoreRoute examples that I've picked up, but all of these are directly related to file extensions. In this case I'm not trying to isolate a file extension, but to simply ignore requests that contain "Rejected-By-UrlScan" in the path.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*robotstxt}", new { robotstxt = @"(.*/)?robots.txt(/.*)?" });
```

The site that I'm working on logs exceptions. Presently when the Rejected-By-UrlScan path appears, this is the exception that gets logged:

```
System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path '/Rejected-By-UrlScan' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

Now, I can extend the Application_Error event in Global.asax to ignore exceptions that contain the text "Rejected-By-UrlScan".  But I would prefer to not even throw the exception in the first place by simply adding the rule.

What is the correct syntax to ignore a route that contains "Rejected-By-UrlScan"?  If you can provide the answer and point me to some documentation that explains the syntax with examples, I would be grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: routes.IgnoreRoute("{*reject}", new { reject = @"(.*/)?Rejected-By-UrlScan(/.*)?" })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question to you is after you ignore it what do you want to do. The reason we ignore static file paths is to avoid the route module from processing static files such as favicon.ico and instead a normal asp.net request process will proceed. The following code will ignore it but the normal asp.net request will result in 404.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{reject}", new { reject = @"(.*/)?Rejected-By-UrlScan(/.)?" })
```

Comment: Dan, I see what you mean. That will still result in a 404, which makes sense. I was just simply trying to avoid throwing an error. Our initial solution in development and test environments was to whitelist rejected file extensions. But we don't have the same control in production, so this initially seemed more expedient. I'll need to rethink this. Thanks so much.